# How to store the weights and retrieve them on R

Tags: r

I am training a net with the package `neuralnet` library of R. I have some problem on retrieve weight once stored in a file. This is the structure

```
>net.out$weights
 [[1]]
 [[1]][[1]]
              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
 [1,] -6.030271716 0.5173197649 -4.759205437
 [2,] 19.013189044 3.0773138715  6.855348584

 [[1]][[2]]
               [,1]
 [1,] -0.6404181227
 [2,]  0.1165101890
 [3,]  0.9999369811
 [4,]  0.6291651704
```

what I am doing is to store in two different tables the two part of the net, so I do

```
 > write.table(net.out$weights[1][[1]][[1]],file='part1.net',quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
 > write.table(net.out$weights[1][[1]][[2]],file='part2.net',quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

but now I don't know how to rebuild the net. I have tried with

```
 >net1<-read.table('part1.net')
 >net2<-read.table('part2.net')
 >net<-data.frame(net1,net2)
```

but doesn't do what I have in mind. What I have to do in order to store and retrieve the wieghts of the net?

Comment: To save R objects "as is", use `dput`.

Comment: Better use `save` to save R objects.

Comment: Save and retrieve. The second part?

Comment: If you put your comment on answer  form, I will sign it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the data in a .Rdata file by means of the `save` function. Afterwards you can load this file by using the `load` function.